# Visual studio 2005 web From application can't support Generic Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2005, generic-handler

Is Dot Net version 2.0 support generic handler? I am trying to retrieve binary image from database to gridview but it's not showing any image. Or not showing me any error.

**Gridview Photo Cloumn :**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
    <ItemTemplate >
      <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height="100px" Width="100px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"ImageHandler.ashx?id_Image="+Eval("ImageId")%>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Generic Handler :**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ImageHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using CSC.Common;
using CSC.DL;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using log4net;
using System.Text;


public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string imageid = "";
        if (context.Request.QueryString["id_Image"] != null)
        {
            imageid = context.Request.QueryString["id_Image"].ToString();
        }

        SqlConnection connection = null;
        //SqlCommand cm = null;
        DataReader dr = new DataReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=datasource;Initial Catalog=myDb;User ID=user;Password=myPass";
        connection.Open();

        //connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigReader.LoginConnString);

        String stringsql = string.Format("Select photo from tblPhoto", imageid);

        dt = dr.GetDataTableByCommand(stringsql, connection);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["photo"]);
            context.Response.End();
            connection.Close();
        }


    }


    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

When gridview bind photo cloumn then it will can ImageHandler class and it will retrive binary image from DB and convert it to image and pass it to gridview. I am using this but it's not showing any image in gridview. There is no error found in my project.

Comment: What is generic handler? Can you share the code? Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: Please google about generic handler in asp.net.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya please review my question details with code as you said.